# Calling a Macro from workSheet by Double Clicking in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to call a `Macro (Rpt1)` in `Module1` by double-clicking a cell in `Sheet2`.  I'm not certain how to do this.  I seem to have the double click event executing from `Sheet2` but I don't know how to call the macro I have in `Module1`.

Comment: Are you not looking for [`Call`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/call-statement)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to paste this code into your SHEET code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Const clickADDRESS As String = "A1" '<--- or whatever cell you want it to be

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(clickADDRESS)) Is Nothing Then
        Call Rpt1
    End If

End Sub
```

which will call the macro in module code (my example)

```
Sub Rpt1()

   MsgBox "This worked"

End Sub
```

By sheet code here's an illustration:
[image]